# How to upload a file from console application to MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, console

I have an MVC application that can accept a file. It basically follows the example shown here for uploading a single file: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5/.

However, I would like to create a command line console utility from which I can upload a file. I think that I very generally understand this would likely involve creating a web request, adding certain headers, and attaching a byte array for the file but I'm a bit lost as to what this entails specifically.

Also for the console application, I will obviously modify the action to return a json result instead of a view.

Comment: In case it's not clear, I am just looking for help on how to setup the web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my gosh it was so much easier than I expected. I just used the `WebClient.UploadFile()` method and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You should add a sample of the code you used so people who end up here get to see how you did it and not just that you were able to do it.